# Modx Revilution error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < lang.js.php:1" in Chrome Dev Tool

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

After installing ModX Revo 2.2.2 and logging in I can see only the menu which is not working properly. Also I've got several errors in my Chrome console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < lang.js.php:1
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream: "/connectors/layout/modx.config.js.php?action=&wctx=mgr". /manager/:16
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < modx.config.js.php:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined index.php:103
(anonymous function) index.php:103
Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined index.php:1
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function ext-all.js:7
Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have some compression moduls, try turn them off. In my case it was

```
php_flag zlib.output_compression On
php_value zlib.output_compression_level 5
```

in .htaccess.